# AntD Calendar with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm creating a React project using Calendar from AntD and also styled-components. I now have this very simple component:

```
import { Calendar } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

const CustomCalendar = () => {
  const StyledCalendar = styled(Calendar)`
    .ant-picker-calendar-date {
      background: #f3faff !important;
      border: 1px solid #c6e2ee !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }

    .ant-picker-calendar-date-today {
      background: #c6e2ee !important;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledCalendar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomCalendar;
```

It looks like this:
[image: calendar]

I wanted to create some more styles: my idea was to set the background-color for all the dates after today to white. I tried to do something like this:

```
const StyledCalendar = styled(Calendar)
  .ant-picker-calendar-date {
      background: #f3faff !important;
      border: 1px solid #c6e2ee !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
    ${({ date }) => {
      const currentDate = dayjs();
      const selectedDate = dayjs(date);
      if (selectedDate.isAfter(currentDate, 'day')) {
        return `
          background-color: #f00 !important;
          color: #fff;
        `;
      }
    }}
  }
;

const MyCalendar = () => {
  const date = dayjs();
  return <StyledCalendar date={date} />;
};
```

It obviously didn't work. So what can be done about it? Is there a way to do what i want?